# How do I scrape page content with a generator?

Tags: jekyll

I have a blog where each post has a bunch of images and videos. I would like to be able to tag each of them with some keywords, and then populate a set of pages based on the tags. For example going to `/photos/car/` would list all images tagged with `car`.

I include images and videos using a simple plugin right now, that essentially only has a render function. I figure I could add the tags there.

But how can I make Jekyll 'scrape' my pages and populate pages with images?

Comment: Which plugin did you use ?

Comment: Just something really basic I whipped up, it's this: https://gist.github.com/bhumphreys/ce0e060f6c8a0f90874925a95352000e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is : ***this is tricky***.

### But why ?

A custom `imgWithTags-tag` liquid tag like `{% img cookie-monster.png  tag2,tag3 %}` can do two things :

- render the html tag
- store tag -> image associations in a `site.taggedImage` variable

As this tag can be used on any post, page or collection document, the `site.taggedImage` variable will only be complete after the render process.

Once the render process is finished, we can grab the `:site, :post_render` hook to process our datas and create Tags pages.

But here, we can no longer rely on things like {% for p in tagPages %}...{% endfor %} to automatically generate links to our pages : rendering is finished.

The trick can be to maintain a link data file by hand, in order to be able to generate links with loops like this `{% for p in site.data.tagPages %}...{% endfor %}`

### Let's give it a try

**NOTE : this works only with Jekyll version 3.1.x (not 3.0.x)**

#### _plugins/imgWithTags-tag.rb

```
module Jekyll
  class ImgWithTags < Liquid::Tag

    # Custom liquid tag for images with tags
    # syntax : {% img path/to/img.jpg coma, separated, tags %}
    # tags are optionnal
    #
    # This plugin does two things :
    #   it renders html tag <a href='url'><img src='url' /></a>
    #   it stores tags -> images associations in site.config['images-tags']

    Syntax = /^(?<image_src>[^\s]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})\s*(?<tags>[\s\S]+)?$/

    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
      super
      if markup =~ Syntax then
        @url = $1
        @tags = $2.split(",").collect!{|tag| tag.strip } if !$2.nil?
      else
        raise "Image Tag can't read this tag. Try {% img path/to/img.jpg [coma, separated, tags] %}."
      end
    end

    def render(context)
      storeImgTags(context) if defined?(@tags) # store datas if we have tags
      site = context.registers[:site]
      imgTag = "<a href='#{ site.baseurl }/assets/#{@url}'><img src='#{ site.baseurl }/assets/#{@url}' /></a>"
    end

    def storeImgTags(context)
      # store tagged images datas in site config under the key site.config['images-tags']
      imagesTags = context.registers[:site].config['images-tags'] || {}

      @tags.each{|tag|
        slug = Utils.slugify(tag) # My tag -> my-tag
        # create a tag.slug entry if it doesn't exist
        imagesTags[slug] = imagesTags[slug] || {'name' => tag, 'images' => [] }
        # add image url in the tag.images array if the url doesn't already exist
        # this avoid duplicates
        imagesTags[slug]['images'] |= [@url.to_s]
      }
      context.registers[:site].config['images-tags'] = imagesTags
    end

  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('img', Jekyll::ImgWithTags)
```

At this point : all tagged images links are rendered and all tags->images associations are stored.

#### _plugins/hook-site-post-render-imagesTagsPagesGenerator.rb

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_render do |site, payload|
  puts "++++++ site post_render hook : generating Images Tags pages"
  imagesTags = site.config['images-tags'] # datas stored by img tag
  linksDatas = site.data['imagesTagsLinks'] # tags pages link in data file
  pagesFolder = 'tag'

  imagesTags.each do |slug, datas|

    tagName = datas['name']
    tagImages = datas['images']
    pageDir =  File.join(pagesFolder, slug)

    tagPage = Jekyll::ImageTagPage.new(site, site.source, pageDir, tagName, tagImages)

    # as page rendering has already fired we do it again for our new pages
    tagPage.output = Jekyll::Renderer.new(site, tagPage, payload).run
    tagPage.trigger_hooks(:post_render)
    site.pages << tagPage

    # verbose check to see if we reference every tag url in out data file
    if !linksDatas.key?(tagName) # check if tag is in imagesTagsLinks data file
      puts "Warning ---------> #{tagName} not in data file"
      puts "Add : #{tagName}: #{tagPage.url}"
      puts "in data/imagesTagsLinks.yml"
      puts
    else
      if tagPage.url != linksDatas[tagName] then # check if url is correct in imagesTagsLinks data file
        puts "Warning ---------> incorrect url for '#{tagName}'"
        puts "Replace : #{tagName}: #{linksDatas[tagName]}"
        puts "by      : #{tagName}: #{tagPage.url}"
        puts "in data/imagesTagsLinks.yml"
        puts
      end
    end

  end
  puts "++++++ END site post_render hook"
end

module Jekyll
  class ImageTagPage < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, tag, images)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir = dir
      @name = 'index.html'

      self.process(@name)
      self.read_yaml(File.join(base, '_layouts'), 'tag_index.html')
      self.data['tag'] = tag
      self.data['images'] = images
      self.data['title'] = "Images for tag : #{tag}"
    end
  end
end
```

And the Tag layout page

#### _layouts/tag_index.html

```
---
layout: default
---
<h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
{% for i in page.images %}
  <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/{{ i }}" alt="Image tagged {{ page.tag }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Here, everything is in place to generate tags page.

We can now do a `jekyll build` and see the verbose output just tell us what to add in `_data/imagesTagsLinks.yml`

#### _data/imagesTagsLinks.yml

```
tag1: /tag/tag1/
tag2: /tag/tag2/
...
```

We can now link to our tag page from everywhere with a simple

```
{% for t in site.data.imagesTagsLinks %}
  <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ t[1] }}">{{ t[0] }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I've told you : it's tricky. But It does the job.

Note: the `img` tag can be improved, and why not a `figure` tag ?

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much!